# How to select Birth date with DateFormat in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a field with birth Date format.

I tried some code but it's showing date as well as time but I want only Date.

is there any perfect way for it?

variables

```
String initValue="Select your Birth Date";
bool isDateSelected= false;
DateTime birthDate; // instance of DateTime
String birthDateInString;
```

here the code for dateTime picker.

```
GestureDetector(
   child: new Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
   onTap: ()async{
     final datePick= await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: new DateTime.now(),
        firstDate: new DateTime(1900),
        lastDate: new DateTime(2100)
       );
    if(datePick!=null && datePick!=birthDate){
      setState(() {
        birthDate=datePick; 
        isDateSelected=true;
        birthDateInString = "${birthDate.month}/${birthDate.day}/${birthDate.year}"; 
      });
     }
   }
 )
```

this widget is for showing Date

```
 new Text(isDateSelected ? "$birthDate":initValue),
```

Comment: there is no any variable with name dateFormat, I have edited my code. Now Check

Comment: This is not localized --> DateFormat.yMd(locale)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define a variable.

```
String birthDateInString;
DateTime birthDate;
```

And then assign it value in your `onTap`

```
birthDateInString = "${birthDate.month}/${birthDate.day}/${birthDate.year}"; // 08/14/2019
```

---

**Update:**

```
GestureDetector(
    child: new Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
    onTap: ()async{
      final datePick= await showDatePicker(
          context: context,
          initialDate: new DateTime.now(),
          firstDate: new DateTime(1900),
          lastDate: new DateTime(2100)
      );
      if(datePick!=null && datePick!=birthDate){
        setState(() {
          birthDate=datePick;
          isDateSelected=true;
          
          // put it here
          birthDateInString = "${birthDate.month}/${birthDate.day}/${birthDate.year}"; // 08/14/2019
          
        });
      }
    }
)
```

Comment: `birthDate.month `,` birthDate.day` , `birthDate.year` , these are fetching from where?

Comment: thank you. I hv update my code  as you said but i'm getting error :  `.month` , `.day` , `.year` are not supporting with variable `birthDate`

Comment: I am still seeing old code, where have you updated it?

Comment: Thank you, worked perfectly. I made some mistakes with datatype that's why was not supporting.

Comment: To declare birthDate variable:
`DateTime birthDate;`

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use `DateFormat` (from [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package) instead of manually forming the display string. This way you can localize the date. e.g.

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
....
new Text(isDateSelected ? DateFormat.yMMMd().format(birthDate) : initValue)
```

Dart Reference: https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html

You need to use right formatter for your usecase.